# R install of rgdal failing in R 3.2.2 OS X 10.11.1 (El Capitan)

Tags: r, installation, gdal, rgdal

Trying to install the `rgdal` library in R.
failing with the following messages

```
> install.packages("rgdal")
Installing package into ‘/Users/rpopat/Library/R/3.2/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0100 1592k  100 1592k    0     0  1235k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 1236k
* installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: clang
configure: CXX: clang++
configure: rgdal: 1.1-1
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... yes
configure: svn revision: 572
checking for gdal-config... no
no
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/Users/rpopat/Library/R/3.2/library/rgdal’
* restoring previous ‘/Users/rpopat/Library/R/3.2/library/rgdal’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/3z/1cdvjt8s5l73fq0k7tzpfll80000gn/T/Rtmpy3KTTV/downloaded_packages’
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.1 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] sp_1.2-1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.2     grid_3.2.2      lattice_0.20-33
```

I have tried...

- installing from bioconductor
- installing GDAL seperately
- downloading an old version of rgdal and installing from local binary (this installs successfully but then crashed when I load the package).

any help is much appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Do you have `gdal` installed? If not you can use homebrew for example to install it

Comment: thanks I installed gdal via homebrew and that worked

Answer (score 0):

Dr Ripley explains that you should use the following code to install rgdal and rgeos:

> setRepositories(ind = c(1,6))  # so you get the dependencies from CRAN
>   install.packages(c('rgeos', 'rgdal'))

and it worked for (el capitan) OS X 10.11.4